# Section title gradient

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, titlesec, gradient

### Background

Writing a manual using KOMA Script. The default fonts are perfect and should not be changed.

### Problem

KOMA Script produces the following section outline:

[image]

The desired outline looks similar to the following (gradient extended to left and right margins):

[image]

The troubles I have encountered:

- The fount for numerals and text changes.
- Retaining the text spacing.
- Expanding or extending the gradient box to:

  - the left and right margins (`\textwidth`?); and
  - a bit larger than the section (or subsection) text's top and bottom margins.

### Source Code

My first attempt resembles:

```
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{%
  \oldsection[#1]{
    \setlength\fboxrule{0pt}%
    \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
    \tikz[background rectangle/.style={left color=blue!20,right color=white},
    show background rectangle] 
    \node [inner sep=0pt] (0,0) {#1};%
  }
}
```

This produces:

[image]

### Update

Changing the text width for the node helps:

```
\node [text width=\textwidth, inner sep=0pt] (0,0) {#1};%
```

This produces:

[image]

### Related

- [How to set the font for a \section title (and chapter etc)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1455/how-to-set-the-font-for-a-section-title-and-chapter-etc)
- [Framing section headings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11998/framing-section-headings)

### Question

How would you implement a margin-to-margin gradient (preferably using TikZ) that is slightly larger than the text?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is relatively easy to achieve using the `titlesec` package:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz,titlesec}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}      % for a test document

\titleformat{\section}[block]%              
    {\usekomafont{sectioning}\usekomafont{section}%
     \tikz[overlay] \shade[left color=blue!20,right color=white] (0,-1ex) rectangle (\textwidth,1em);}%    
    {\thesection}%                   
    {1em}%
    {}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument 
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Note the following:

- `\usekomafont{sectioning}\usekomafont{section}` sets the font to whatever is chosen using the KOMA Script styling mechanism.
- The `[overlay]` option of `\tikz` means that TikZ won't take any space.
- This breaks if the title is longer than a line.

---

*Edit:* Here is second version, that works with long lines and does not ignore ascenders and descenders. The code is more complicated, though. It draws the whole section heading with TikZ.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz,titlesec}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\newcommand\boxedsection[1]{{%
    \usekomafont{sectioning}\usekomafont{section}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt, inner ysep=0.3ex]
        \node[anchor=base west] at (0,0) (counter) {\thesection};
        \path let \p1 = (counter.base east) in node[anchor=base west, text width={\textwidth-\x1-0.33em}] (content) at ($(counter.base east)+(0.33em,0)$) {#1};
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
            \shade[left color=blue!20,right color=white] let \p1=(counter.north), \p2=(content.north) in
            (0,{max(\y1,\y2)}) rectangle (content.south east);
        \end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}}

\titleformat{\section}%              
    {}%
    {}%
    {0pt}%
    {\boxedsection}%

\begin{document}
\chapter{test}
\section{Overview}
\section{Implementation}
\section{a very long section entry a very long section entry a very long section entry a very long section entry a very long section entry}
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 8):

It is not recommended to use `titlesec` together with a KOMA-Script class. But with KOMA-Script Version 3.19 or newer you can redefine `\sectionlinesformat` to get the desired section title layout.

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
  \renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
    \ifstr{#1}{section}
      {\tikz\node[inner xsep=0pt,inner ysep=0.3ex,left color=blue!20,right color=white]
        {\parbox{\textwidth}{\raggedsection\@hangfrom{\hspace*{#2}#3}{#4}}};}
      {\@hangfrom{\hspace*{#2}#3}{#4}}%
}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Note that this works also for `\addsec` and `\section*`.

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
%\providecommand*\Ifstr{\ifstr}% needed up to and including KOMA-Script version 3.27, see https://komascript.de/faq_deprecatedif

\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
  \renewcommand\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
    \Ifstr{#1}{section}
      {\tikz\node[inner xsep=0pt,inner ysep=0.3ex,left color=blue!20,right color=white]
        {\parbox{\textwidth}{\raggedsection\@hangfrom{\hspace*{#2}#3}{#4}}};}
      {\@hangfrom{\hspace*{#2}#3}{#4}}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext} %dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{test}
\section{Overview}
\addsec{Section without number}
\section*{Second section without number}
\section{Implementation}
\section{a very long section entry a very long section entry a very long section entry a very long section entry a very long section entry}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's great. I was wondering... how do I extend this for subsections?