# Table example made in Google Docs - how to make (would one make) this in LaTeX?

Tags: tables, formatting, tabularx

edit -> the emphasis on Google Docs might be a bit much, basically it's just a little table thing, it's not something unique to Google Docs thats just what I happened to use to make this.

I made this in Google Docs, and I was going to do this in LaTeX but I can't seem to get this table made, I'm not even sure if tables the proper name for it. Perhaps there's another name / environment for this kind of thing that I'm unaware of.

[image]

So how would you go about making that in LaTeX?

Thanks!

---

I've looked at some of the other links on here, a few things are coming up about converting google docs but there doesn't seem to be anything solid. I can't download HTML and use Pandoc because there's CSS in there as well...

Comment: What have you tried so far in LaTeX? A combination of [`colortbl`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/colortbl) and [`array`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) packages should be able to get the job done.

Comment: hey @PaulGessler, I've tried using the tabular environment and multirow within that and there was something else (that I've forgotten). I was reading a book (which didn't give much info on tables to be fair) but said that people often use tables when they shouldn't, so I thought perhaps this was in fact called something else when created with LaTeX, a floating box environment or something idk.

Comment: I'm guessing that you're saying that you would make this using colortbl and array packages then Paul ?

Comment: You don't need `multirow`. Paul's suggestion would work for this - it is not an especially sophisticated design, so I'd stick to the simple solution.

Comment: OK cheers, everything kept overflowing the boxes and stuff. So how you would do this @cfr is 'combination of colortbl and array packages' ? thanks]#

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's straightforward to create such a table using the `xcolor` and `colortbl` packages. You didn't indicate the preferred width of the table, so I've assumed it should be as wide as the text block.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx,lipsum,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X} % allow hyphenation
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|Y|Y|}
\hline
\rowcolor{LightBlue} Something & Another\\
\hline
\lipsum*[2] & \lipsum*[4]\\
\hline
\rowcolor{LightBlue} Example & Demonstration\\
\hline
\lipsum*[2] & \lipsum*[4]\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* -- As @barbarabeeton has pointed out in a comment, the horizontal lines in the preceding table are spaced very narrowly and created a cramped look. One way to improve the table's look is to insert (typographic) struts. Insert a "top" strut if there's an `\hline` immediately ahead of the material, insert a "bottom" strut if there's an `\hline` immediately after the material, and insert both a top *and* a bottom strut if the material is in a header row. (For more on typographic struts in a LaTeX document see, e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50355/5001.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx,lipsum,ragged2e}
\newcommand\sometext{Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et, tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi.}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X} % allow hyphenation

%% From the article "Correct spacing for tables and arrays" 
%% by Claudio Beccari, p. 10 of TeX and TUG News 1993 (Vol. 2, No. 3). 
\newcommand\T{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}       % Top strut
\newcommand\B{\rule[-1.2ex]{0pt}{0pt}} % Bottom strut
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|Y|Y|}
\hline
\rowcolor{LightBlue} Something & Another\T\B \\
\hline
\T\sometext & \sometext\B \\
\hline
\rowcolor{LightBlue} Example & Demonstration\T\B \\
\hline
\T\sometext & \sometext\B \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks a lot @Mico. For this kind of thing would you have the contents of the table (the paragraphs of text) in a separate file and 'include' (insert...) them into the table or just have it all in the same place? cheers

Comment: @user3130747 - I'd place the text directly inside the cells.

Comment: thanks a lot @Mico, this is a lot simpler than I thought it would be actually (based on some of the generated code from a latex tables generator site that I had used). cheers

Comment: i'd like to see a little more vertical clearance at least around the headings.  would also improve the (tops of the) text boxes.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Thanks. I've posted an addendum that discusses how one may use typographic struts to create a more open look (while still dealing with `\hline`s and vertical lines).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple approach with `tabulary` and `xcolor`.

```
\documentclass{article}

% FONT
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgheros}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}

% TABLE FORMATS
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

% Format header rows uniformly
\newcommand{\tableheader}[1]{%
    \cellcolor{cyan}\textbf{#1}%
}

% DUMMY TEXT FOR EXAMPLE
\newcommand{\cicero}{% 
    Quo usque tandem abutere, Catilina, patientia nostra? 
    quam diu etiam furor iste tuus nos eludet? 
    quem ad finem sese effrenata iactabit audacia? 
    Nihilne te nocturnum praesidium Palati, 
    nihil urbis vigiliae, 
    nihil timor populi, 
    nihil concursus bonorum omnium, 
    nihil hic munitissimus habendi senatus locus, 
    nihil horum ora voltusque moverunt?%
}



\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{|L|L|}
\hline
\tableheader{Something} & \tableheader{Another}\\ \hline
\cicero                 & \cicero\\ \hline
\tableheader{Example}   & \tableheader{Demonstration}\\ \hline
\cicero                 & \cicero\\ \hline
\end{tabulary}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You may want to explain how the `L` column type of the `tabulary` environment, which is used in your answer, differs from the `X` column type of the `tabularx` package. Having a brief explanation of this type may help (non-expert) readers form an opinion as to which environment may be best-suited to meet their typesetting needs.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** This is official account of Docx2Latex

We have just launched Google Docs-add on which combines the power of Latex and ease of word processors and cross Referencing too.

You can take advantage of its LaTeX code generation capabilities to get the code for any kind of table without worrying about tedious job of remembering different types of syntax for a normal table, table with merged cells, long table, table with colored background etc.

Following are some cool features (related to table) that Docx2LaTeX add-on supports.

1. Converts **normal tables**.
2. Converts **long tables**(spreading across multiple pages).
3. Converts table with **merged cells** (row, columns or both simultaneously).
4. Detects the cell **background colors**.
5. Intelligently **adjusts the widths** of columns to save table from running **out of right margin**.

This really helps in **saving time** and catch up on deadlines.
For more feature of add-on refer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/423698/159282

**Add-On Link:**
[Docx2Latex Google Docs Add-on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/docx2latex/egbfhgljgndebjfacgpkjchhpfbcpegl?utm_source=permalink)

**Watch Demo:** 
[Short Demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBVqgzbImug)