# Online latex editing for large groups/large documents

Tags: editors

I realise this might be off topic - but is there a google-docs style latex editor "out there" (so cloud based file management). Which is free, yet has higher limits? Sharelatex I can't use enough collaborators (10 max, need at least 20), while with writelatex the file limit is quickly reached (60 max, we're creating a document about 500 pages with likely 300ish images) - and it doesn't support xelatex which we'd like to use.

So is there a free solution out there I am missing?

Comment: There is docs.latexlab.org which has already been mentioned on this site here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173317/is-there-a-latex-wrapper-for-use-in-google-docs but I have no idea if it has the features you are looking for.

Comment: Honestly, do you know _any_ IT project that is (1) produced from sourcecode, (2) managed by 20 people at once, (3) freehosted and (4) not crashing completely?

Comment: Github? Google docs?

Comment: etherpad + LaTeX? http://www.pendicular.net/etherlatex.php

Comment: @dcmst - that looks "promising" sadly the project seems to be abandoned since 2010. Having dozens of bugs (one which prevents inclusion of .tex files, another where tkiz pictures are not supported).

Comment: @paul23 Github is not really exactly just freehosted --- you need to maintain your projects, deal with the commits etc. Google docs have no source code people would edit directly. Yes, both of them work, but because they work differently from what you seek. My point is that you seem to want to automate stuff beyond the level at which it's maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm one of the founders of writeLaTeX, and I think you can use our free plan to do what you need:

1) We do now support XeLaTeX, you can choose it as the build engine by clicking on the gear icon in the editor, see this post for more details: https://www.writelatex.com/blog/167

2) Although our basic free plan has a fair-use limit of 60 files per project, we're happy to increase it for you for a specific project - just send us a link to the project via https://www.writelatex.com/contact.

You can also now get a free month of Pro+ very easily (see https://www.writelatex.com/space when you're logged in), which would give you the higher limits automatically.

I hope this helps, and if you have any questions please let me know - we try to be flexible whenever we can to accommodate different size projects!

Answer (score 0):

## Auto-Latex Equations

If you ever want to type LaTeX math equations directly in Google Docs, you can use [Auto-Latex Equations add-on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-latex-equations/iaainhiejkciadlhlodaajgbffkebdog?utm_source=stackOverflow3).

All you have to do is type an equation within delimiters, like $$55 + \sqrt{5}$$ and it can be rendered in super high quality at whatever time you like by rendering all the equations in your document. If you mess up, you can always undo them, edit them, then re-render them.

You can get it at [the Google Docs add-ons store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-latex-equations/iaainhiejkciadlhlodaajgbffkebdog?utm_source=stackOverflow3). This is admittedly only high-quality images of the equations, but you can easily edit them whenever you want. While it's not a full LaTeX environment, at least it is better than not having enough space for many collaborators.

Comment: Good point! Other than Mr. Hammersley's generous offer above, I am not aware of any LaTeX editors that allow the scale that OP wants. I offered a solution I thought might be better than the alternative of no editor at all, and understand if this is not the use case for most LaTeX users. I will clarify this further in the post.