# Setting color text to improve eye movement from the of one line to the start of the next?

Tags: formatting, color, line-breaking, tcolorbox

The web site  http://www.beelinereader.com/ provides a chrome browser
extension which colorizes paragraphs so that moving your eyes from one 
line to the next is much quicker than with just black text.

See http://www.calpoly.edu/~mstankus/beeline-paragraph.png for 
a graphic which should make this clear.

Can this be done in LaTeX in a semi-automatic or automatic
way?

Mark

Comment: As a non-related comment, you may also be interested in Spirtz. The theory is that if your eye is fixed on one point rather than jerking across the page reading, you brain has to only process information (instead of information + eye control).

Google Spritz. There is a commercial and an open source implementation. For most things online, they provide a bookmarklet.

Comment: you can type `beeline` into the site search box:-) http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131919/1090