# Dyspraxia package

Tags: color, packages

Does anyone know a package or a solution adapted for people with dyspraxia that would alternate the color of each line (on line with one color and the next line another color) ?

Comment: You can give a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/510811/82917 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131883/82917.

Comment: Thank you ! This is exactly what I was looking for (with the wrong keywords...) !

Comment: You might ask for this feature to the author of the `chickenize` package.