# How to shade text in different colors?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, shading

I need a single character in two colors. Figuring I could use the `shadings` library of TikZ, I followed the manual (section 23.4.1, the TikZ example):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,shadings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=mixed 4]
  \node[text=transparent!0] {$4$};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
\fbox{\tikz[scale=10]\shade[path fading=mixed 4,top color=orange,bottom color=purple] 
  (0,0) rectangle (2ex,2ex);}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, the result is no good for two reasons:

1. The surrounding box is far too large; it's not possible to *use* the 
   character in text of formulae.
2. Only the center part of the shading is visible in the character, rendering it almost invisible.

How can I make the shading apply *only* to the character, without any surrounding space?

If it's easier, I can also do without the shading but a hard change of colors, that is something like this (gimped):

[image]

The angle of the separation line is not that important.

Comment: If the cut is exactly vertical there's a possibly simpler solution using `clipbox`: [Character with two colors - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201596/character-with-two-colors)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Here is another suggestion:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=5mm]{standalone} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\newcommand\fadingtext[3][]{%
  \begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=fading letter]
    \node[text=transparent!0,inner xsep=0pt,outer xsep=0pt,#1] {#3};
  \end{tikzfadingfrompicture}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(textnode.base)]
    \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,#1](textnode){\phantom{#3}}; 
    \shade[path fading=fading letter,#2,fit fading=false]
    (textnode.south west) rectangle (textnode.north east);% 
  \end{tikzpicture}% 
}

\begin{document} 
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
\fbox{%
  \fadingtext[scale=10]{top color=orange,bottom color=purple}{$4$}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can use this to color text:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=5mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\newcommand\fadingtext[3][]{%
  \begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=fading letter]
    \node[text=transparent!0,inner xsep=0pt,outer xsep=0pt,#1] {#3};
  \end{tikzfadingfrompicture}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(textnode.base)]
    \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,#1](textnode){\phantom{#3}}; 
    \shade[path fading=fading letter,#2,fit fading=false]
    (textnode.south west) rectangle (textnode.north east);% 
  \end{tikzpicture}% 
}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document} 
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
\fbox{%
  \fadingtext[scale=4]{top color=orange,bottom color=purple}{$4$}%
}

A short test with green and purple: \fadingtext{left color=green,right color=purple}{green to purple} 

\noindent\fadingtext{top color=blue,bottom color=red,middle color=green!80!black}{\parbox[b]{\linewidth}{\strut\lipsum[1]}}
\end{document}
```

---

Here is an additional suggestion with a sharp border between the two colors:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\tikzset{
    bctleft/.style={.},
    text left/.style={bctleft/.append style={#1}},
    bctright/.style={.},
    text right/.style={bctright/.append style={#1}},
}
\newcommand\bicolortext[2][]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(n.base),inner sep=0pt,outer xsep=0pt,#1]{
      \node(n){\phantom{#2}};
      \foreach \a/\c in {north west/bctleft,south east/bctright}{
        \begin{scope}
          \clip(n.south west)--(n.\a)--(n.north east)--cycle;
          \node[\c]at(n){#2};
        \end{scope}
      }}}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{text left=orange,text right=purple}
    \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
    \fbox{%
      \bicolortext[scale=4,transform shape]{$4$}%
    }

    A short test with green and purple: \bicolortext[text left=green, text right=purple]{green to purple} 

    \noindent\bicolortext{\parbox[b]{\linewidth}{\strut\lipsum[1]}}
\end{document}
```

---

With TikZ version 3.0 you can also use the `transparency group=knockout` option. Then it is possible to shade diagonal. But AFAIK only Acrobat Reader shows the correct result, because only this viewer is able to handle transparencies.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=5mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\fadingtext[3][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(textnode.base)]
    \node[shade,#2,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,#1,shading angle=45](textnode){\phantom{#3}};
    \begin{scope}[transparency group=knockout]
      \fill[white](textnode.south west)rectangle(textnode.north east);
      \node[opacity=0,inner sep=0pt,outer xsep=0pt,#1]{#3};
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}% 
}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document} 
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
\fbox{\fadingtext[scale=10]{top color=orange,bottom color=purple}{$4$}}

A short test with green and purple: \fadingtext{left color=green,right color=purple}{green to purple} 

\noindent\fadingtext{top color=blue,bottom color=red,middle color=green!80!black}{\parbox[b]{\linewidth}{\strut\lipsum[1]}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have trouble seeing how the first (relevant) part differs from my approach, aside from wrapping it in a nicer command. But, apparently, the specific combination of which `sep`s to set to `0` and where to scale matters. Curious.

Answer (score 32):

Another solution exploiting the text rendering modes of the PDF specification to render the text as a clipping path:

```
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\shadetext[2][]{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{{\special{pdf:literal 7 Tr }#2}}%
  \tikz[baseline=0]\path [#1] \pgfextra{\rlap{\copy0}} (0,-\dp0) rectangle (\wd0,\ht0);%
}
\begin{document}
Some
\shadetext[left color=yellow, right color=red, middle color=purple, shading angle=45]{\Large\bfseries shaded}
text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Although it uses PDF specials, the nice thing about this approach is it is easy to extend it to use an arbitrary picture:

```
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\newbox\textpicturebox
\tikzset{text picture/.style={%
  path picture={%
   \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\textpicturewidth{\wd\textpicturebox}%
   \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\textpictureheight{\ht\textpicturebox+\dp\textpicturebox}%
   \pgftransformshift{\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{center}}%
   #1}}}%
\newcommand\shadetext[2][]{%
  \setbox\textpicturebox=\hbox{{\special{pdf:literal 7 Tr }#2}}%
  \tikz[baseline=0]\path \pgfextra{\rlap{\copy\textpicturebox}} [#1] (0,-\dp\textpicturebox) rectangle (\wd\textpicturebox,\ht\textpicturebox);
}
\begin{document}
\shadetext[fill=black, text picture={
  \tikzset{shift=(90:2)}
  \fill [green!75!brown] (-0.25,0) rectangle (0.25,-7);
  \fill [green!75!brown] (0,-7) [rotate=-45]  arc (270:-90:0.5 and 2);
  \fill [green!75!brown] (0,-7) [rotate=45]  arc (270:-90:0.5 and 2);
  \foreach \i [evaluate={\o=mod(\i/30,2)*100;}] in {0,30,...,330}
    \fill [red!\o!pink] 
       (0,0) -- (\i:3) .. controls ++(\i:1cm) and ++(\i+30:1) .. (\i+30:3) -- cycle;
  \fill [yellow] circle [radius=1.5];
  }]{\Large\bfseries\begin{minipage}{4in}\lipsum[1]\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Who wouldn't want a flower-shaped shading?

Comment: This solution is great. Just notice that `middle color` option must be placed after `left color` and `right color`.

Answer (score 19):

Here is a solution with `pstricks`, and more precisely with `pst-grad` and  `pst-text`. It is compilable with pdf LaTeX, and the box size can be changed with `\psframebox[framesep=…]{…}`:

```
\documentclass[pdf, x11names]{article}
\usepackage{pst-grad,pst-text}
\psset{framesep=2pt}
\begin{document}

Some text
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\psframebox[linecolor = Coral1!20]{%
    \pscharpath[linestyle=none,%
    fillstyle=gradient,gradend=IndianRed4,gradbegin=IndianRed1,
    gradmidpoint=1]{\LARGE\bfseries 4}}
    & \psframebox[linecolor = Coral1!20]{%
    \pscharpath[linestyle=none,%
    fillstyle=gradient,gradend=IndianRed4,gradbegin=IndianRed1,
    gradmidpoint=1]{\Large\bfseries 4}}
    & \psframebox[linecolor = Coral1!20]{%
    \pscharpath[linestyle=none,%
    fillstyle=gradient,gradend=IndianRed4,gradbegin=IndianRed1,
    gradmidpoint=1]{\bfseries 4}}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you compile this file using `pdflatex` directly or you need to go around `dvi2pdf`?

Comment: Directly. You have to set `--enable-write18` (MiKTeX) or `--shell-escape` (TeX Live, MacTeX) as a compiler option (it loads auto-pst-pdf). Or you may compile with XeLaTeX. **Added:** I modified my answer to have a tighter box.

Answer (score 13):

It is possible to create a more reasonable box by printing the character again and anchoring the shading at this node:

```
\fbox{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=10]
    \node [text=white,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (textnode) {$4$};
    \shade[path fading=mixed 4,fit fading=false,top color=orange,bottom color=purple]
    (textnode.south west) rectangle (textnode.north east);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

[image]

I followed [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45744/how-to-put-color-gradient-to-desired-text-only/46034#46034).

Answer (score 3):

One could use the `gradient-text` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{gradient-text}

\begin{document}

\gradientRGB{Test}{0,255,0}{255,0,0}

\[
\gradientRGB{42}{0,255,0}{255,0,0} + 1 = 42
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This was my package. Notice that it doesn't seem as good when the gradient text has few characters, because it simply gives every single character a single color.

Comment: @youthdoo A fun little package! I'm very glad the package exists and brings a bit of colour to the TeX world :)