# Masking vectorized content in pgf

Tags: tikz-pgf

In section 106.4 of the [pgf manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) (page 1068), one learns how to mask pixel based images.

I was wondering if it is possible to mask vectorized based content like text in a `\node`.

Of course in that case one "rasterizes" content. This however doesn't have to mean that the vectorized aspect is completely removed: one could split up the content in square cells. Each of the cells is given a certain transparency, but still has a vectorized description. For instance if there is a triangle drawn in a cell, it is still a vectorized triangle, but with transparency (for instance equal to 0.5). Is there an straightforward way to achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at the `tikzfadingfrompicture` environment and for example [How to shade text in different colors?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/192496).