# Fill text with image?

Tags: graphics, typography, text

I've searched a lot and can't find any answers to this, so I suspect the answer is no.

I'm trying to achieve a text fill effect like you can do in PowerPoint, like so:

[image: Image text fill]

It's scaling the image exactly to the bounds of the text (whether it spans across multiple lines or not), and filling the text with that image.

Is this possible to do in LaTeX?

Thanks!

Comment: yes possibly easier in pstricks (and so latex) than with pdflatex, but probab;y doable in tikz as well for pdflatex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite simple – just a couple of lines of code — with `pstricks`, more precisely with the `pst-text` and `pst-fill` packages.

Also, with `auto-pst-pdf`, it works with `pdflatex`  if you add to the compiler the switch `-shell-escape` (for TeX Live, MacTeX) or `--enable-write18` (MiKTeX):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{pst-text, pst-fill, auto-pst-pdf}%
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Piero_di_Cosimo_1}\medskip

\Huge\sffamily\bfseries
\begin{center}
SOMETIMES TO UNDERSTAND \\
A \begin{pspicture}\psboxfill{\includegraphics{Piero_di_Cosimo.eps}}%
    \pscharpath[fillstyle=boxfill, linestyle=none]{ WORD’S MEANING}
    \end{pspicture} YOU \\
NEED MORE THAN A \\
DEFINITION
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, Bernard. This gave me what I needed to do more effective searching.  I ended up going with the solution given in the second part of this answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/192990/146997