# How to place a color gradient text node inside a tikzpicture (absolute positioning)

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, positioning, gradient

I want to put a color gradient to a "Desired Text Only" but then I want to be able to position it inside a `tikzpicure`. I already checked [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45744/how-to-put-color-gradient-to-desired-text-only#) describing a way to put gradient color to a section heading.

Problem is: I am unable to freely place such a node inside a `tikzpicure`environment.

Here is a MWE of what I tried:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,patterns}

%******************************************************************
%
% Defining a new coordinate system for the page:
%
% --------------------------
% |(-1,1)    (0,1)    (1,1)|
% |                        |
% |(-1,0)    (0,0)    (1,0)|
% |                        |
% |(-1,-1)   (0,-1)  (1,-1)|
% --------------------------
\makeatletter
\def\parsecomma#1,#2\endparsecomma{\def\page@x{#1}\def\page@y{#2}}
\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{page}{
    \parsecomma#1\endparsecomma
    \pgfpointanchor{current page}{north east}
    % Save the upper right corner
    \pgf@xc=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@yc=\pgf@y%
    % save the lower left corner
    \pgfpointanchor{current page}{south west}
    \pgf@xb=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@yb=\pgf@y%
    % Transform to the correct placement
    \pgfmathparse{(\pgf@xc-\pgf@xb)/2.*\page@x+(\pgf@xc+\pgf@xb)/2.}
    \expandafter\pgf@x\expandafter=\pgfmathresult pt
    \pgfmathparse{(\pgf@yc-\pgf@yb)/2.*\page@y+(\pgf@yc+\pgf@yb)/2.}
    \expandafter\pgf@y\expandafter=\pgfmathresult pt
}
\makeatother
%******************************************************************

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=tikz]
    \node [text=transparent!20] {\bfseries Piece of text to be colored};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node [text=gray!50,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (textnode)% 
    {\bfseries Piece of text to be colored};
    \shade[path fading=tikz,fit fading=false,left color=blue,right color=black]%
        (textnode.south west) rectangle (textnode.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Such code succeeded in putting a color gradient into my piece of text.

[image]

But then, when I try to place the latter somewhere inside the `tikzpicture environment` adding a position to the node such as:

```
\node [text=gray!50,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (textnode) at (page cs:0,0) 
    {\bfseries Piece of text to be colored};
```

it seems that only the piece of text moves and not the color gradient and I obtain this :

[image]

What am I doing wrong? How can I freely place such color gradient piece of text inside a `tikzpicture`?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what's wrong with OP's code, but using [Mark Wibrow's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/192990/1952) `\shadetext` command inside a `tikzpicture` seems to work.

[image]

Following code includes `\shadetex` commands as `node's` text part. This way `tikzpicture` absolute positioning can be used. Third example shows that already defined `current page` node allows to obtain similar results than OP's new coordinate page system.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,patterns}

%******************************************************************
%
% Defining a new coordinate system for the page:
%
% --------------------------
% |(-1,1)    (0,1)    (1,1)|
% |                        |
% |(-1,0)    (0,0)    (1,0)|
% |                        |
% |(-1,-1)   (0,-1)  (1,-1)|
% --------------------------
\makeatletter
\def\parsecomma#1,#2\endparsecomma{\def\page@x{#1}\def\page@y{#2}}
\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{page}{
    \parsecomma#1\endparsecomma
    \pgfpointanchor{current page}{north east}
    % Save the upper right corner
    \pgf@xc=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@yc=\pgf@y%
    % save the lower left corner
    \pgfpointanchor{current page}{south west}
    \pgf@xb=\pgf@x%
    \pgf@yb=\pgf@y%
    % Transform to the correct placement
    \pgfmathparse{(\pgf@xc-\pgf@xb)/2.*\page@x+(\pgf@xc+\pgf@xb)/2.}
    \expandafter\pgf@x\expandafter=\pgfmathresult pt
    \pgfmathparse{(\pgf@yc-\pgf@yb)/2.*\page@y+(\pgf@yc+\pgf@yb)/2.}
    \expandafter\pgf@y\expandafter=\pgfmathresult pt
}
\makeatother
%******************************************************************

\newcommand\shadetext[2][]{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{{\special{pdf:literal 7 Tr }#2}}%
  \tikz[baseline=0]\path [#1] \pgfextra{\rlap{\copy0}} (0,-\dp0) rectangle (\wd0,\ht0);%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node at (page cs:0,0) {\shadetext[left color=blue, right color=black]{\bfseries Piece of text to be colored}};

    \node[anchor=north east] at (page cs:1,1) {\shadetext[left color=red, right color=yellow]{\bfseries Piece of text to be colored}};

    \node[anchor=south west] at (current page.south west) {\shadetext[left color=green, right color=purple]{\bfseries Piece of text to be colored}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```