# Text along path and gradient on each character

Tags: gradient, tikz-path

I am trying to draw a large colored text along a path, where the color follows a gradient.

I found posts describing how to draw text along a path and posts showing how to draw colored text with gradients, but the two techniques don't seem to mix as easily.

The effect I'm trying to obtain is shown in the picture below:[image]

Any idea how I could obtain this?

--- EDIT 2 ---

Preferably, I'd like to have a gradient visible on each character rather than a single, solid color on each character.

--- EDIT ---

I tried to mix a text along a path, like the following one:

```
\resizebox{0.5\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[left color=orange!30, right color = orange,decoration={text along path,
      text={|\Huge\bfseries|GRADIENT},text align={center}},font=\tiny,decorate] (155:2.75) arc (155:25:2.75);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

with a colored text with gradient, e.g.:

```
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=mypic]
  \node [text=transparent!20]
    {\fontfamily{ptm}\fontsize{45}{45}\bfseries\selectfont GRADIENT};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill [white] (-5,-1) rectangle (5,1);
  \shade[path fading=mypic,fit fading=false, left color=orange!30,right color=orange]
    (-5,-1) rectangle (5,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but I have no idea how to use my first tikzpicture as a tikzfadingfrompicture. Simply replacing one for the other as follows (of course) doesn't work:

```
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=mypic]
\draw[text=transparent!20,decoration={text along path,
      text={|\Huge\bfseries|GRADIENT},text align={center}},font=\tiny,decorate] (155:2.75) arc (155:25:2.75);
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill [white] (-5,-1) rectangle (5,1);
  \shade[path fading=mypic,fit fading=false, left color=orange!30,right color=orange]
    (-5,-1) rectangle (5,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Add the code of your unsuccessful attempts.

Comment: @AndréC Done, but really I have no clue how to proceed, as I'm not familiar with tikz.

Answer (score 3):

My try: (Reference: pgfmanual.pdf (V3.1.1), p. 651)

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,math}
\begin{document}

\bfseries
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={text effects along path,
text={GRADIENT}, text align={center},
text effects/.cd,
character count=\i, character total=\n,
characters={text along path, evaluate={\c=\i/\n*100;},
text=brown!\c!black}}]
\path [decorate]
(0,2) .. controls ++(0,1) and ++(0,1) .. (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is page 551 of which version of Tikz?

Comment: Sorry, Version 3.1.1.

Comment: No, this is not page 551 of manual 3.1.1
[Where can we find the old TikZ and pgf manuals?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/557439/where-can-we-find-the-old-tikz-and-pgf-manuals)

Comment: oh, sorry, it is 651.

Comment: Nice, but am I right that in this solution every character has a single color (and thus no gradient within a character)?

Comment: yeah. if you want real gradient, follow [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/345047/108724).

Comment: @Maiaux Change the title of the question to specify that you want to vary the colour for each character.

Comment: How do we use other fonts? For example, I want to use \Huge \bsifamily or \Large \calligra. But unfortunately, I could not work out where to give these fonts commands.  @user108724