# shaded letters in chapter

Tags: chapters

This week I have wrote this word :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{Monvert}{RGB}{229,36,36}

\definecolorseries{MONVERT}{rgb}{last}{Monvert}{black}

\resetcolorseries[15]{MONVERT}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}
  \Huge
\textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{P}\textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{s}\textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{y}\textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{c}\textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{h}\textcolor{MONVER
T!!+}{o}\textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{P}\textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{a}\textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{t}\textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{h}\textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{o}\textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{l}\textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{o}\textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{g}\textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{y}
\end{document}
```

my question is :
if I want to customise chapter's and section's  with the same way, How can I do this ? Any insight or solution will be appreciated

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Sorry I have a problem with my PC !

Comment: You know, you could just say `\textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{PsychoPathology}`...but frankly I don't know the purpose behind doing that.

Comment: My problem is how can do the same color in all my chapter's or section's

Comment: @Haouam: I think you should clearify your question. What should be coloured? The chapter/section titles?

Comment: in my example psychopathology is colored in shaded color if i want to color all my chapter's(test in the example) at the same way  how can do this?

Comment: Is it clear now ?

Comment: @Haouam: I think, I have some idea what you mean

Comment: @Haouam: In my point of view, the term `shade` is misleading. You are requesting a colour gradient

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45744/how-to-put-color-gradient-to-desired-text-only and the answer to you question is there.

Answer (score 4):

A preliminary version, without `\section` parts. It will fail most probably, if the chapter title will contain macros instead of unexpandable material.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{Monvert}{RGB}{229,36,36}

\definecolorseries{MONVERT}{rgb}{last}{Monvert}{black}

\resetcolorseries[50]{MONVERT}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\usepackage{xstring}

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\shadetitle}{+m}{%
  \StrLen{#1}[\titlelength]
  \foreach \x in {1,...,\titlelength} {%
    \textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{\StrChar{#1}{\x}}%
  }%
}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak}{\Huge \bfseries \shadetitle{#1}\par\nobreak}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}



\chapter{Test it with a very long title}
  \Huge
  \textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{P}\textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{s}\textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{y}\textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{c}\textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{h}\textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{o}\textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{P}\textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{a}\textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{t}\textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{h}\textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{o}\textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{l}\textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{o}\textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{g}\textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{y}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit** Some improved version

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{Monvert}{RGB}{229,36,36}

\definecolorseries{MONVERT}{rgb}{last}{Monvert}{black}

\resetcolorseries[100]{MONVERT}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\NewDocumentCommand{\shadetitle}{+m}{%
  \StrLen{#1}[\titlelength]%
  \foreach \x in {1,...,\titlelength} {%
    \textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{\StrChar{#1}{\x}}%
  }%
}

\makeatletter

%\xpatchcmd{\@ssect}{\hskip #1\relax #5}{#4{\hskip #1\relax \shadetitle{#5}}}{\typeout{Patch success}}{\typeout{Patch failure}}

% Does not work so far :-(
%\xpatchcmd{\@ssect}{\@svsechd{#4{\hskip #1\relax #5}}}{\@svsechd{#4{\hskip #1\relax \shadetitle{#5}}}}{\typeout{Patching ssect}}{}


% Patching the section header command
\xpatchcmd{\@sect}{\def\@svsechd{%
    #6{\hskip #3\relax
      \@svsec #8}%
  }}{%
    \def\@svsechd{%
      #6{\hskip #3\relax
        \@svsec \shadetitle{#8}}%
    }}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@sect}{\interlinepenalty \@M #8\@@par}{          \interlinepenalty \@M \shadetitle{#8}\@@par}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak}{\Huge \bfseries \shadetitle{#1}\par\nobreak}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak}{\Huge \bfseries \shadetitle{#1}\par\nobreak}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter}{\huge\bfseries \shadetitle{\@chapapp}\space \shadetitle{\thechapter}}{}{}

\makeatother
\begin{document}



\chapter{Test it with a very  title}
\section{And a shorter title}
  \Huge
  \textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{P}\textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{s}\textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{y}\textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{c}\textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{h}\textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{o}\textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{P}\textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{a}\textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{t}\textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{h}\textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{o}\textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{l}\textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{o}\textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{g}\textcolor{MONVERT!!+}{y}

\chapter*{Some other chapter}
\section*{Some other section}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I am pretty aware, that this is a hack only. There must be better ways, of course. Most likely, it's better to colorize the tokens and not trying to identify each character in the input.

Comment: Thank you for your help, can I change Chapter 1 in the same color ?

Comment: @Haouam: Yes, but do you want to restart the sequence both for `Chapter 1` and the title or should it just continue?

Comment: I want to continue

Comment: Nicely horrendous (but that's just my personal view) ;).

Comment: Note, that this is a **hack**

Comment: @cfr: Stickleress  to the point ;-). Well, honestly, I would not use it for my personal documents. But it was (and is!) a challenge