# How to use tkiz point from two different nodes on separate axis?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I know I need to use the x from the `counter` node and the y from the `rectangle` node, but so far the right syntax has eluded me.

Green indicates what I'm trying to fill, and red indicates the where the line should extend to.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[letterpaper,asymmetric,left=108pt,right=54pt,top=41pt,bottom=41pt,headsep=13pt,headheight=14pt,footskip=23pt,marginparwidth=72pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[compact,explicit,calcwidth]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\setkomafont{section}{\normalfont\bfseries}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\newlength\titlemarginwidth
\setlength\titlemarginwidth{54pt}

\newcommand\boxedsection[1]{{%
  \usekomafont{sectioning}\usekomafont{section}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt,y=1pt,inner sep=0, inner ysep=0.7ex]
    \node[anchor=base west,text width=\titlemarginwidth-\columnsep,color=white] at (0,0) (counter) {\hspace{1ex}\thesection};
    \node[anchor=base west,text width=\textwidth] at ($(counter.base east)+(\columnsep,0)$) (rectangle) {#1};
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \fill[color=black] let \p1=(counter.north), \p2=(counter.north) in (0,{max(\y1,\y2)}) rectangle (counter.south east);
        \draw[black,thick] let \p1=(counter.north), \p2=(counter.north) in (0,{max(\y1,\y2)}) -- (rectangle.north east);
        \draw[black,thick] (rectangle.south west) -- (rectangle.south east);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
  \end{tikzpicture}
}}

\titlespacing{\section}{-\titlemarginwidth}{1em}{0em}
\titleformat{\section}[block]
  {}%
  {}{0pt}{\boxedsection{#1}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Testing One Two Three!}
\section{Extremely long section title that is absolutely absurd and obnoxious that goes on forever and ever and ever and ever!}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

I switched to `tikz` after having trouble with spacing using just `titlesec` rules and boxes.

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12266/section-title-gradient) was extremely helpful in getting me started.

Comment: `(counter|-rectangle)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the perpendicular coordinate system (refer to the PGF documenation (pp. 130-131)); in fact, you don't need here the `let` syntax at all. I also suppressed some redundant code from your example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[letterpaper,asymmetric,left=108pt,right=54pt,top=41pt,bottom=41pt,headsep=13pt,headheight=14pt,footskip=23pt,marginparwidth=72pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[compact,explicit,calcwidth]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\setkomafont{section}{\normalfont\bfseries}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\newlength\titlemarginwidth
\setlength\titlemarginwidth{54pt}

\newcommand\boxedsection[1]{{%
  \usekomafont{sectioning}\usekomafont{section}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt,y=1pt,inner sep=0, inner ysep=0.7ex]
    \node[anchor=base west,text width=\titlemarginwidth-\columnsep,color=white] at (0,0) (counter) {\hspace{1ex}\thesection};
    \node[anchor=base west,text width=\textwidth] at ($(counter.base east)+(\columnsep,0)$) (rectangle) {#1};
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \fill[color=black] (0,0|-counter.north) rectangle (counter.south east|-rectangle.south east);
        \draw[black,thick] (0,0|-counter.north) -- (rectangle.north east);
        \draw[black,thick] (0,0|-rectangle.south west) -- (rectangle.south east);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
  \end{tikzpicture}
}}

\titlespacing{\section}{-\titlemarginwidth}{1em}{0em}
\titleformat{\section}[block]
  {}%
  {}{0pt}{\boxedsection{#1}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Testing One Two Three!}
\section{Extremely long section title that is absolutely absurd and obnoxious that goes on forever and ever and ever and ever!}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]