# \section{} within a tcolorbox

Tags: table-of-contents, tcolorbox

I'm working on a LaTeX template for an article appendix that will be used by a whole team. My current challenge is creating a color-filled box around `\section{}` headings, while maintaining the qualities of the `\section{}` command.

I've addressed this task by creating a `tcolorbox`, the look of which I'm happy with, but the functionality of the `\section{}` command has been lost. I need some help remedying this problem.

I've named the tcolorboxes "`sectionboxes`" as seen in the working example below, and would like to simply be able to search my colleagues' files and replace all `\section{}` with `\sectionbox{}` to apply this layout.

I need the `\sectionbox`es to have the same functions as the `\section` commands, i.e.

1. to  display the section count in the in-text title itself (e.g. "1. Section title" and not just "Section title"), and
2. for the `\sectionbox{}` content to be displayed in the table of contents with its corresponding section count.

To create the boxes, I use the package `tcolorbox` and the command below.

In-text, where I would normally write `\section`, I write:

```
\stepcounter{section}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{SECTION_NAME}
\sectionbox{\MakeUppercase{SECTION_NAME}}
```

This at least adds the `\sectionbox` content to the ToC, but without the count number. It is also too many lines to be efficient.

I feel like I've tried everything, including numerous other ways of creating the boxes, but I just can't make it work. Does anyone have a solution?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{title}
\author{author}
\date{\today}

\newcommand{\sectionbox}[1] {
\begin{tcolorbox}
             [
              colback=purple!100,% background
              colframe=purple,% frame colour
              coltext=white, % text color
              width=\linewidth,%
              height=0.7cm, 
              halign=center,
              valign=center,
              fontupper=\large\bfseries,
              arc=0mm, auto outer arc,
             ]
    {#1}
\end{tcolorbox} 
} %

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\sectionbox{Contents}
\vspace{-1cm}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\stepcounter{section}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{SECTION-NAME}
\sectionbox{\MakeUppercase{SECTION-NAME}}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Thank you for taking the time to post a nice illustrative example document along with your question.

Comment: You may be interested in some alternative/related approaches to boxing section headings discussed in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/179019/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11998/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34288/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/318637/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/431142/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/254318/35864 (especially the last one seems interesting)

Comment: In addition to those mentioned by @moewe, here's a solution I did for the `memoir` class: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/522778/87678

Comment: Thanks everyone, these are great! Also got a terrific answer in another forum, using an xpatch command: https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=33217

Answer (score 1):

All you need is `\refstepcounter` and `\numberline`.  Hint, use a normal `\section` command and compare the entries in the aux file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{title}
\author{author}
\date{\today}

\newcommand{\sectionbox}[1] {
\begin{tcolorbox}
             [
              colback=purple!100,% background
              colframe=purple,% frame colour
              coltext=white, % text color
              width=\linewidth,%
              height=0.7cm, 
              halign=center,
              valign=center,
              fontupper=\large\bfseries,
              arc=0mm, auto outer arc,
             ]
    {#1}
\end{tcolorbox} 
} %

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\sectionbox{Contents}
\vspace{-1cm}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\refstepcounter{section}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\string\numberline{\thesection}SECTION-NAME}
\sectionbox{\MakeUppercase{SECTION-NAME}}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```