# Renewing `\tableofcontents` in LaTeX

Tags: table-of-contents, article, package-writing

From [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/526837/235428) answer, I tweaked it a little bit to redefine `\section` as follows:

```latex
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}[1]%
{
\begin{tcolorbox}
             [
              colback=gray!50!white,% background
              colframe=gray!50!white,% frame colour
              coltext=black, % text color
              width=\linewidth,%
              height=0.7cm,
              halign=left,
              valign=center,
              fontupper=\large\bfseries,
              arc=0mm, auto outer arc,
             ]
    {\stepcounter{section}\arabic{section}$\,|\quad$ #1}
\end{tcolorbox}
}
```

However, the moment I use `\tableofcontents`, it does not work as expected (I am using an `article` class, by the way.)

Then, by scanning `article.cls`, the definition of `\tableofcontents` is as follows:

```latex
\newcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \section*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    }
```

I tried replacing `\section` with `\oldsection`, but it does not work. Can someone help, please?

---

Edit: MWE

```latex
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{sample}

\RequirePackage{letltxmacro, tcolorbox}
\LetLtxMacro{\oldsection}{\section}
\renewcommand{\section}[1]%
{
\begin{tcolorbox}
             [
              colback=gray!50!white,% background
              colframe=gray!50!white,% frame colour
              coltext=black, % text color
              width=\linewidth,%
              height=0.7cm,
              halign=left,
              valign=center,
              fontupper=\large\bfseries,
              arc=0mm, auto outer arc,
             ]
    {\stepcounter{section}\arabic{section}$\,|\quad$ #1}
\end{tcolorbox}
}

\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \oldsection*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    }
\endinput
```

```latex
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{sample}

\begin{document}
     \tableofcontents
     
     \section{I}
          \subsection{1}
          \subsection{2}
     \section{II}
          \subsection{1}
          \subsection{2}
\end{document}
```

---

Edit: Used `\LetLtxMacro` instead of `\let`

Comment: Instead of these sniple4s, 9lease post a full but minimal example such that others can 5est your code. Additionally, exactly what do you mean by "it doesn't work"

Comment: Even though you typed some words wrong, I understand that they are "snippets, please, test". Thank you for insisting.

Comment: The original `\section` command takes an optional argument, which determines what's written to the aux file (and eventually to the toc file, which is where the contents of the Table of Contents are assembled). If left blank, the optional argument of `\section` defaults to the command's mandatory argument. Your redefinition of `\section`, however, guarantees that *nothing* is written to the aux file. Was that deliberate?

Comment: @Mico Are you referring to this?
`\newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex\@minus -.2ex}{2.3ex \@plus.2ex}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}`

Comment: Yes, but somewhat indirectly. If you examine the code for `\@startsection` (contained in the file `latex.ltx`, the LaTeX "kernel"), you'll find (for unstarred section-like commands), the instruction `\@dblarg{\@sect{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}`, where `\@sect`, finally, contains the instruction `\addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{...}`. Unfortunately, this setup was not designed to be easy to adjust. I recommend you look into the capabilities of the `titlesec` and `sectsty` for solutions that are feasible in finite time.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for suggesting. I feel like I'm embarassed now since the MWE's worked last night, where the "Contents" just did not work without me knowing _how_ it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The challenge here is that `\section` does not actually take a single argument. Instead, it can take three forms:

```
\section{...}
\section[...]{...}
\section*{...}
```

You've only accounted for one of those three and, as you've discovered, `\tableofcontents` uses the last form.

One approach to what you want would be to use the `xparse` package to redefine `\section`:

```
\RequirePackage{xparse}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{s o m}{%
   \IfBooleanTF {#1}
     {\@ssect{\z@}{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{2.3ex \@plus.2ex}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{#3}}
     {%
   \IfNoValueTF{#2}
     {\@mysection{#3}{#3}}
     {\@mysection{#2}{#3}}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\@mysection}{m m }{
      \begin{tcolorbox}
             [
              colback=gray!50!white,% background
              colframe=gray!50!white,% frame colour
              coltext=black, % text color
              width=\linewidth,%
              height=0.7cm,
              halign=left,
              valign=center,
              fontupper=\large\bfseries,
              arc=0mm, auto outer arc,
             ]
    {\refstepcounter{section}\thesection $\,|\quad$ #2}
  \end{tcolorbox}
  \sectionmark{#1}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{%
    \ifnum 1>\c@secnumdepth\else
      \protect\numberline{\thesection}%
    \fi
    #1}
  }
```

A couple notes on the above:

1. This is all untested. Old habit from when I taught a creating LaTeX style classes entirely off the top of my head writing everything longhand on a whiteboard.
2. I used the internal `\@ssect` command with the arguments that would be passed to it from the article class for the starred version of `\section` so you don't need to change `\tableofcontents`.
3. I changed `\stepcounter` to `\refstepcounter` so references to section numbers will still work.
4. I changed `\arabic{section}` to `\thesection`. You should always prefer `\theCOUNTER` to `\arabic{COUNTER}` unless you have some compelling reason to do otherwise.
5. I added support for page headings and table of contents. You might not be using the former but you're definitely using the latter. The code is adapted from the LaTeX core.